# Turn a byte of hex into a char string

Tags: c, string, char, printf

When I attempt to convert one byte of hex into a char string I find that it takes 3 bytes. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

If I have less than 3 bytes I get an error: "Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted."

What am I doing wrong? Surely the hex value 0xF1 should fit into `char str[1]`? Why should I have to declare a 3 byte array to assign a 1 byte value?

```
char str[3];
sprintf(str, "%02X", 0xF1);
```

The content of `str`is 0x0026fd18 "F1"

Comment: There is an "F", a "1", and a `NUL`. That is 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that's trying to print "F1" into the string followed by a null terminator - this would be three bytes. That's the whole point of the sprintf function - it formats the input into a readable string. If you're trying to simply assign the hex value of 0xF1 to a char, you would do it like this:

`char str = (char)0xF1`

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: Glad I could help! Just remember to accept my answer if you're satisfied with it.